# auto-resize a XIB file to be as the screen size

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xib

I have a View Controller which has a scrollView embedded inside. In this Scroll view I have adding 4 views which are XIB file views. The XIB files size are 'Inferred' although appear to be iphone5 sizing. When loaded they are not auto-resizing to be the size of the screen, they are staying at iphone5 size.

How can I make the XIB file be the same size as the screen it is loading into?

EDIT:

I have also tried changing the the size of the nib files through the code like this:

```
 // 1) Create the three views used in the swipe container view
        let AVc :AViewController =  AViewController(nibName: "AViewController", bundle: nil);
        let BVc :BViewController =  BViewController(nibName: "BViewController", bundle: nil);
        let CVc :CViewController =  CViewController(nibName: "CViewController", bundle: nil); 
        let DVc :DViewController =  DViewController(nibName: "DViewController", bundle: nil);

        AVc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        BVc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        CVc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        DVc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

        // 2) Add in each view to the container view hierarchy
        //    Add them in opposite order since the view hieracrhy is a stack

        self.addChildViewController(DVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(DVc.view);
        DVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(CVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(CVc.view);
        CVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(BVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(BVc.view);
        BVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(AVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(AVc.view);
        AVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);
```

This still has no affect and it loads the wrong size.

Comment: I have not used any autolayout

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use size classes  and then apply the necessary constants at first it'll be a little difficult but by time you'll learn how to apply the size classes and constants.
[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) are the links where you'll find the best [examples](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Auto-Layout then you can add the four views simply by for loop:

```
let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let width = bounds.size.width
let height = bounds.size.height

var yAxis: CGFloat = 0.0

for i in 0...3 {
   let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, yAxis, width, height)

   swift i {
       case 0:
          view1.frame = rect
       case 1:
          view2.frame = rect
       case 2:
          view3.frame = rect
       case 3:
          view4.frame = rect
       default:
          break
   }

   yAxis = yAxis + height
}
```

Where view1, view2, view3 and view4 are your 4 xib views.
Also, set the content size of the scroll view to height yAxis.

**Recommended, You should use AutoLayout it will reduce the lines of code.**

Comment: I am not using auto layout, but thanks I'll give this a go.

Comment: Thanks I have already done some thing similar to this and still has no affect. I have added my code to show what i have done.